Windows Forms Font Scaling and DataGridView
I'm developing a basic form on a high DPI device.  When i run it, the font in the DataGridView is probably twice the size of the form's font!  Even though it uses the same font object!
I'm pretty sure it's do do with scaling etc.  And I've tried fixes from this post to no avail: GUI sample of high DPI screen using PowerShell
Is there any way to fix the basic example below?  Thanks!
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial",'34',[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular,[System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel)


# Create a new form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "DataGridView Example"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600, 400)
$form.Font = $Font 

# Create a Label
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Text = "Example DataGridView"
$label.AutoSize = $true
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)

# Create a DataGridView
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 50)
$dataGridView.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(560, 300)
$dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font = $font

# Create a DataTable and add columns
$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$table.Columns.Add("ID", [int])
$table.Columns.Add("Name", [string])
$table.Columns.Add("Age", [int])

# Add example rows to the DataTable
$table.Rows.Add(1, "John Doe", 30)
$table.Rows.Add(2, "Jane Smith", 25)
$table.Rows.Add(3, "Michael Johnson", 40)

# Bind the DataTable to the DataGridView
$dataGridView.DataSource = $table

# Add controls to the form
$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)

# Show the form
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
[void] $form.ShowDialog()


See whether changing the DPI awareness mode of the window (and a couple of other things, related to the Font) can solve the problem. Check the notes here

Hmm.  I saw a note on that post and I think the issue is powershell_ise related.  It appears to display ok if i execute via poweshell.exe.....  I'm assuming I need to make powershell_ise DPI aware somehow?

That note is more related to the result of ::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault($false) when run in the IDE. Anyway, you just need to test the code running it from the console of pwsh.exe

ISE isn't reliable to test your form code, use the CLI or even better test your code in VSCode with the PowerShell extension. You will get much better coding experience there. ISE is prehistoric.
